Does ST-LINK or FT232H works with Renesas MCU?
How can I debug do hardware debug, I have ST-LINK and FT232H, would it work with Renesas MCU? Also, if anyone has used e2 studio, then please guide me.
I have a project for a sensor and in that sensor's API folder contents some .c test files (which do some initialization test on the sensor and PCB), now how do I test that specific code directly with my PCB/MCU in real time?

Similar question: Can I use ST-Link programmer for non-ST chips?

For debugging your Renesas MCU, I’d say your ST-LINK should work fine if your MCU supports SWD or JTAG. The FT232H isn’t the best choice for direct debugging, though.
Now, when you're using e² studio, just import your sensor API files and set up a debug configuration for your specific MCU. Load your code onto the board, and you're good to go!
To test those .c files, make sure they have a main function. Initialize your MCU, run those tests, and you’ll see how everything works in real time.
